# Return column name from index and value with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I am looking for a way to find a column name with index number and value.

```
original = {'col1': [1, 2,0,9], 'col2': [3, 4, 2,5]}
original = pd.DataFrame(data=original)

    col1    col2
0   1        3
1   2        4
2   0        2
3   9        5
```

For example, I want to find where is 2 is recorded in the column.
I only know index number 1 and value 2 but do not know what is column name.

I am expecting to return the only column name col1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` to select the row, and `idxmax` to select the column:

```
(original.loc[1] == 2).idxmax()
# 'col1'
```

If "1" is an integer position rather than index label, use `iloc` for row selection:

```
(original.loc[1] == 2).idxmax()
# 'col1'
```

Answer (score 0):

This solutions uses [numpy.argwhere](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

`original.columns[np.argwhere(original.iloc[1,:] == 2)[0][0]]`